# When scrolling an animated ImageView, two images are shown

Tags: android, animation, android-listview

I have an `ImageView`.I want to animate a SINGLE image clicking it. 
But when SCROLLING I see TWO images animating. Why?

```
Animation  animationLeft;
ImageAdapter imageAdapter;ListView listView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
      animationLeft=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.transform_left);


     listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     imageAdapter=new ImageAdapter(this, items,images);
    listView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
      position,
                long arg3) {
            ImageAdapter mAdapter = (ImageAdapter)parent.getAdapter();

            final View vImage=   mAdapter.getView(position, view, 
    parent).findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
             animate(vImage);


        }
    });

}

public void animate(View v){
         TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation
(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
0.0f);
            anim.setDuration(6000);
             v.startAnimation(anim);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `public void animate(View v)` is focusing on very view that is capable of animating the image , and hence TWO images is animating.....

Try to set animation separately on Imageview like below

```
public void animate(View v){
ImageView thumbPhoto=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.0f);
        anim.setDuration(3000);
        thumbPhoto.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Try to call this method where it is possible ,probably in the onCreate(), so that image animate as soon as Activity apperars